# Kendo charts disappear in internet explorer 8 in a fraction of second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, charts

I have an asp.net web application in which I am using telerik and kendo ui for some gauges and charts. Now my controls render properly in chrome and safari but kendo charts disappear in a second when the page loads.

The arrow shows the charts where kendo ui is used.

I've added the following tag in the head section but the charts do not show up in IE 8.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

[image]

Any ideas will be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was very simple. I had to downgrade the kendo libraries and it worked.